# Delete current file and keep my saved csv

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete a excel file that is currently open. I do not have a specific name so it has to be 
`Kill .FullName`

When I do This:

```
    Dim relativePath As String
relativePath = "\\FILES\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh_mm") & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\PROGRAM.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV _
, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True


On Error Resume Next
With ActiveWorkbook
.Saved = True
.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
Kill .FullName
.Close False
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

It does not kill my initial file only the saved `PROGRAM.csv`
Can anyone help me delete my initial opened file?

Comment: I suspect you want `ActiveWorkbook` rather than `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: I've tried it but it does not kill my file. I will update my full code.

Comment: Then you don't want to delete the open workbook, you just want `Kill relativePath`

Comment: This will kill my 'relativepath' backup but not the initial file I have opened. Maybe I need to copy the filename first and then`kill` the copied name..?

Comment: Yep, that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you `SaveAs` first time, add a line `originalName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName`and then further down anywhere after you `SaveAs` the original file, add `Kill originalName`